# How to calculate number of digits in a string in Assembly(MIPS)

Tags: assembly, histogram, mips

I need to write a code in assembly(MIPS) that calculates the number of times each digit (0 to 9) is shown up in a string.

I have this code i wrote so far:

```
                .data
DigitStr:       .asciiz "9012132323224645546"
ResultArray:    .space 10
                .text
                .globl main


main:
li $t0, 0   #string index
li $t1, -1  #the number to compare 0-9
la $t2, ResultArray

la $s0, ResultArray

li $t5, 0

loop:
beq  $t5, 11, print
addi $t1, $t1, 1
lb $t2, ResultArray($t1)       #count the number of times a number is showed up
li $t2, 0
j nestedLoop


nestedLoop:
lb $t3, DigitStr($t0)
move $t4, $t3
andi $t4,$t4,0x0F
beq $t4, $t1, increment
beq  $t0, $zero, loop   #branch if last character is null
j nestedLoop

increment:
addi $t2, $t2, 1


print:
move $a0, $s0         
li $v0, 4            #print string
syscall
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You certainly aren't writing into your `ResultArray` at all ... and even if you were, those would be numbers so you can't print them as a single string. You never seem to go back to `loop` either.Not that you'd need to if you used the simple indexing method. Anyway, show your algorithm/pseudocode and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: You have algorithmic problems, not necessarily MIPS assembly problems.  Suggest you try writing this in pseudo code or in C, getting it working there, and then transcribe that faithfully into MIPS assembly -- this is often easier than writing MIPS assembly from scratch without a working algorithm to start with.